# How to remove empty xmlns="" on repeating elements in JAXB writing to file?

Tags: java, jaxb, java-17, xmlstreamwriter

I have data objects that is marshalled to xml and written to file.
All objects are generated with xjc, so it is not possible to change objects, package-info.java etc.

The **MainElem** contains a list of **RepeationElems**.
When marshaling the MainElem with this code:

```
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MainElem.class);
 Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 jaxbMarshaller.marshal(mainElemObj, sw);
```

I get the following output, which is OK, and validates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mainelem xmlns="http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1">
    <repeatingelem>
        <id>123344567</id>
        <type>A</type>
    </repeatingelem>
    <repeatingelem>
        <id>98775312</id>
        <type>B</type>
    </repeatingelem>
</mainelem>
```

However I ran in to problems with "Out Of Memory". (The RepeatingElem contains much more data than showed, and there can be several 1000 of them)

As a solutions I followed this StreamingMarshal solution [How to stream large Files using JAXB Marshaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775202/how-to-stream-large-files-using-jaxb-marshaller)

That is write directly to file and one object at the time. Doing this I dont get the same output, and dont know how to get it right.

New code:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RepeatingElem.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
xof.setProperty(XMLOutputFactory.IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES, true);

XMLStreamWriter xmlOut = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("myXmlFiel"));
xmlOut.setDefaultNamespace("http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1");
xmlOut.writeStartDocument();
xmlOut.writeStartElement("mainelem");

for(RepeatingElem elem: elemList){
   JAXBElement<RepeatingElem> element = new JAXBElement<>(new QName(null, "repeatingelem"), RepeatingElem.class, elem);
   marshaller.marshal(element, xmlOut);  
}

xmlOut.writeEndDocument();
xmlOut.close();
```

This results in a xml that is not OK, and it does not validate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<mainelem xmlns="http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1">
    <repeatingelem xmlns=""
        xmlns:ns2="http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1">
        <ns2:id>123344567</ns2:id>
        <ns2:type>A</ns2:type>
    </repeatingelem
    <repeatingelem xmlns=""
        xmlns:ns2="http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1">
        <ns2:id>98775312</ns2:id>
        <ns2:type>B</ns2:type>
    </repeatingelem>
</mainelem>
```

I dont want the empty **xmlns=""** and not the ns2: either.
Also the xml-tag should have encoding.

I have tried with and without:

- `xof.setProperty(XMLOutputFactory.IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES, true);`
- `xmlOut.setPrefix("ns2", "http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1");`
- `xmlOut.setDefaultNamespace("http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1");`
- `xmlOut.writeStartElement("ns0", "mainelem", "http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1");`

Nothig removes the xmlns="" on the RepeatingElem.

The XSD look like:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1" 
    targetNamespace="http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0.0">
  <xsd:element name="mainelem">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="repeatingelem" type="Rep" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:complexType name="Rep">
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="type" xsd:string"/> type="TimeStamp"/>
        ...
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

---

**UPDATE**
I have updated the jaxb version to 4.0.4 with no change in the output

If I remove:

```
xof.setProperty(XMLOutputFactory.IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES, true);

xmlOut.setDefaultNamespace("http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1");
```

and add:

```
xmlOut.writeAttribute("xlmns", "http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1");
```

I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<mainelem xmlns="http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1">
    <repeatingelem xmlns:ns2="http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1">
        <ns2:id>123344567</ns2:id>
        <ns2:type>A</ns2:type>
    </repeatingelem>
    ...
```

So the empty xmlns="" was fixed!
But it does not validate, I think the **ns2** is the problem.
How do I solve this?

---

**EDIT:** the following removed the problematic ns2

Changing:

```
JAXBElement<RepeatingElem> element = new JAXBElement<>(new QName(null, "repeatingelem"), RepeatingElem.class, elem);
```

To:

```
JAXBElement<RepeatingElem> element = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1", "repeatingelem", XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX), RepeatingElem.class, elem);
```

Comment: Which version of jaxb runtime do you use ?

Comment: Not sure these are in the gradel-file
 'jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-api:10.0.0' 
'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0' 
'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the newer version of jaxb 4.0.4 (thanks @Laurent Schoelens) and some changes the result is now validating.
The empty xmlns-attribute and the faulty namspace ns2 is gone!

**NEW CODE:**

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Repeatingelem.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

XMLStreamWriter xmlOut = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("myXmlFile"));
xmlOut.writeStartDocument();
xmlOut.writeStartElement("mainelem");
xmlOut.writeAttribute("xmlns", "http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1");

for(RepeatingElem elem: elemList){
   JAXBElement<RepeatingElem> element = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1", "repeatingelem", XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX), Repeatingelem.class, elem);

   marshaller.marshal(element, xmlOut);  
}

xmlOut.writeEndDocument();
xmlOut.close();
```

The output is as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<mainelem xmlns="http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1">
    <repeatingelem xmlns="http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1">
        <id>123344567</id>
        <type>A</type>
    </repeatingelem>
    <repeatingelem xmlns="http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1">
    ...
```

Still the repeating-element has an extra xmlns attribute that is not present when marshalling "all-in-one" with the Mainelem, but it validates so maybe that is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to latest `jaxb-ri` / `jaxb-impl` version 4.0.4

This is a known issue in 4.0.3 which was fixed [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/pull/1752) in 4.0.4 release

Comment: I updated the version. I still get the same output

Comment: Updatet question with info

Comment: Could you share your `pom.xml`

Comment: Since we use gradle and not maven we don't have one

Comment: Then could you share your gradle build file ? :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Changing the QName-constructor resolved the issue
        JAXBElement<Kund> element = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("http://schema.blah.com/xx/xxx/1", "repeatingelem", XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX), Repeatingelem.class, t);